# Flexbox Expandable Items in Row, stop row expanding with item

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have items in flexbox showing in 2 columns. The items are expandable (similar to dropdowns). When the user clicks on the item it expands, but also expands the row with it. I am wanting the item to expand when clicking but not the row.

What is happening:
[image]

What is supposed to happen:
[image]

The code for the columns:

```
list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  max-width: 1096px;

  @include mediaQuery(max, 1080px) {
    width: 940px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, $tablet) {
    width: 526px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, $mobile) {
    width: 335px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, 320px) {
    width: 285px;
  }
}
```

I have tried to find similar questions here on stack, but it seems that no one else is running into this or this has not been asked before.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

ADDON TO QUESTION:

```
<div className="analyzed-genes-list">
  {
   data.map((item, index) => (
    <GeneCard key={index} gene={item.gene} cancers={item.cancers} positives={this.state.posGenes} traits={this.state.traits} />
   ))
  }
 </div>
```

GeneCard.js

```
<div className={this.state.toggleBody ? "gene-card-active" : "gene-card"}>
  <div className="gene-card-title" onClick={this.showBody} style={{backgroundImage: this.state.toggleBody ? `url(${ChevronUp})` : `url(${ChevronDown})`}}>
    <span className="gene-name">{this.props.gene}</span>
      {
       this.state.pos ?
        <span className="pos-variant">{this.state.variants} variant
         { this.state.variants > 1 ? 's' : null }
           &nbsp;detected</span>
           :
           <span className="variant">Variant not detected</span>
         }
        </div>
        {
          this.state.toggleBody ?
          <div className="gene-card-body">
            {
              this.props.cancers.map((cancer, index) => (
                <span key={cancer} className="cancer">
                  {cancer}
                  {
                    index === this.props.cancers.length - 1 ?
                    null
                    :
                    ','
                  }
                  &nbsp;
                </span>
              ))
            }
          </div>
          :
          null
        }
      </div>
```

Comment: would it be feasible to calculate the positions before rendering?

Comment: otherwise, your best bet is likely to use an extra box with absolute positioning, i'll make a mock

Comment: Can you post the html code or a runnable example? By default, flex will try to make all items in the same container the same height.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I added the React JSX that is rendering this for you, if you need more let me know

Comment: Can you also post the JSX for `GeneCard` as well? I want to see the html element with the `.link` class and how it relates to it's siblings.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda added

Comment: Sorry man, I'm still not seeing it. Where is the `list` class being used? On each list or the main container?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda just realized that I cut the class name, `list` should actually be `analyzed-genes-list`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a css solution using the columns feature of css.

```css
.wrapping-list {
  columns: 2;
}

.list-item {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: red;
  break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.list-item-expansion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-list">
    <div class="list-item">
      test
      <div class="list-item-expansion">
        expansion
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
    <div class="list-item">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: happy with this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick example of how this can be achieved with css.

When using absolute positioning, the box does not take up space, so the other boxes do not move down. The relative positioning is necessary to get the positioning right.

```js
function activate() {
    const listItem = document.getElementById("listitem1");
    const expansion = document.getElementById("expansion1");
    expansion.classList.toggle("active");
    expansion.style.top = listItem.clientHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.listitem {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.listitem-expanded {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.listitem-expanded.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="listitem1" class="listitem" onclick="activate()">
    <div style="position: relative">
      <div id="expansion1" class="listitem-expanded">expansion</div>
    </div>
    test
  </div>
  <div class="listitem">test</div>
  <div class="listitem">test</div>
  <div class="listitem">test</div>
  <div class="listitem">test</div>
  <div class="listitem">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this isn't exactly what I am looking for...the list still needs to push down the content. This is a good example of how to make your dropdown (expandable area) overlay the next item. Which can also be done with `z-index` on the active class

Comment: oh, i didn' t correctly see what the problem was in the figures, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one way to do it...not a CSS solution, however...

Basically, you take the data coming in and divide it in half. So you'll be rendering 2 different arrays in React.

List:

```
componentDidMount(){
  let first = data.slice(0, Math.round(data.length / 2));

  let second = data.slice(Math.round(data.length / 2), data.length);

   this.setState({
      firstHalfData: first,
      lastHalfData: second
    });
}
```

JSX:

```
<div className="analyzed-genes-list">
   <div className="analyzed-genes-list-col">
      {
        this.state.firstHalfData.map((item, index) => (
         <GeneCard key={index} gene={item.gene} cancers={item.cancers} positives={this.state.posGenes} traits={this.state.traits} />
           ))
         }
       </div>
     <div className="analyzed-genes-list-col">
        {
          this.state.lastHalfData.map((item, index) => (
           <GeneCard key={index} gene={item.gene} cancers={item.cancers} positives={this.state.posGenes} traits={this.state.traits} />
            ))
         }
       </div>
     </div>
```

the CSS:

```
.analyzed-genes-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  max-width: 1096px;
  width: 100%;

  @include mediaQuery(max, 1080px) {
    width: 940px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, $tablet) {
    width: 526px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, $mobile) {
    width: 335px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, 320px) {
    width: 285px;
  }
}

.analyzed-genes-list-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 526px;

  @include mediaQuery(min, 1081px) {
    width: 508px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, 1080px) {
    width: 440px;
  }

  @include mediaQuery(max, $tablet) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

if someone has a solution for CSS I am all ears!